# AutoExec in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Word macro (.dotm) in the Word startup folder. When it gets loaded, it automagically calls

```
Sub Autoexec
    Call myMacro
End Sub
```

as explained [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/auto-macros).

Is there a way to achieve the same effect with an Excel AddIn (.xlam) stored in the Excel startup folder?

Comment: You mean to load an Addin when Excel starts?

Comment: No, it gets loaded, but I want code to execute automatically the moment it's loaded. @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns

Comment: Please try `Workbook_Open()` event. https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/run-macro-automatically-opening-workbook/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Workbook_Open as Maddy suggested in his comment, that is the recommended mtehod. Or you put in a normal module a macro which is named a little bit differently than the one in word. This also works in an AddIn

```
Sub auto_open()
    MsgBox "Welcome"
End Sub
```

Also have a look for the naming convention here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-runautomacros-method-excel